# Why player is lagging (local multiplayer)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Why my player lagging? I mean he is moving with 2 fps for enemy. Example: Player1 moves, in his screen all is ok. But player2 see player1 with 2 fps. And the same with player1.
Here is my prefab, and yes, I can't use RigidBody Transform

[image: prefab]

Answer (score 2):

I think you could find the answer with very little research. The answer is quite simple though.

The reason why it's working perfectly on the client which owns the networking transform is because his input is directly reported to the game. On the other hand, the 2nd player has to send the information about his position to the host or simply the other players. The information is only sent a couple times per seconds.

You could increase the message sending rate of the networking but that's not really a good option. The best option would be to smooth the player's movement by assuming where he is going to be or move the player after it has moved already.

Here is a link about it : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Glm0nJ4sO5E